# UPDATE Command для DataAdapter

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

Допустим, имеется DataTable t1 с полями f1,f2,f3 и нужно, что бы DataAdapter произвел вот такое обновление на реальной БД:

```
UPDATE table1
SET p1=f1,p2=f2
WHERE p3=f3
```

Как нужно сконфигурировать объект команды, что бы DataAdapter все сделал правильно?

Основная загвоздка в параметрах.

Я правильно понимаю, что мне нужно конструировать вот таким конструктором

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cdd6yck6(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Чем является srcColumn? Это колонка в DataTable или реальной таблице?

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать этот запрос на DataTableAdapter.UpdateCommand

```
UPDATE table1
SET p1=@f1,p2=@f2
WHERE p3=@f3
```

Comment: Ну там же нужно передать SqlCommand=> настроить параметры и все такое, наверное... Или я ошибаюсь

Comment: Если вы используете визуальный DataSet то не надо настроить параметры, если нет вы можете создать DataTableAdapter вручную и использовать где вам нужно. DataTableAdapter сам разбирается с параметрами. Создать DataTableAdapter вручную - [DataTableAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand.aspx)